# Pass a line and file contents into a program as stdin

Tags: macos, bash, script-fu

I'm trying to pass in a file and a single line of code into a program, say example.

My line:

```
i := 1;
```

My file (file):

```
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

Input to program:

```
i := 1;
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

I'm thinking it would be a one line such as:

```
example < `echo "i := 1;\n" cat file`
```

or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is here string:

```
example <<< `echo "i:=1" && cat file`
```

From bash manual:

```
3.6.7 Here Strings

A variant of here documents, the format is:

     <<< word

The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{ echo 'i := 1;' ; cat myfile.txt ; } | example
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(
echo "i := 1"
cat file
) | program
```

Comment: No, that redirects to a file named `program`, and you are missing a command separator.

Comment: Sorry, comment seems to have gone in the wong input box?!

Comment: It works because it's split over multiple lines. It can be done on a single line, but I prefer to spread things like this out if I can - especially in a script file. Bash and Ksh both allow command input over multiple lines in the terminal.

Comment: I'll happily confirm that it works for anyone who was wondering - just entered it that way into a handy shell and it does exactly what it says on the tin, as well as being a slightly clearer layout than the one-line versions (and, strangely, shorter - a combination of brevity *and* clarity? Is that even legal?)